# About Euler's formula $e^{ix}=\cos x+i\sin x$

Tags: complex-numbers, exponential-function, matlab

I think I probably miss something. Can you tell me what it is?

In my assumption, that any given 'x' value, 
$$e^{ix}=\cos x+i\sin x$$

But, why don't I get the same value in the equation when I calculate it in matlab?

```
x=pi/3;
exp(x) = 2.8497
cos(x)+sin(x) = 1.3660
```

I know I miss out 'i' in the equation. 
Honestly, I don't know that what the 'i' serves to get the actual value.
Can anybody help?

Comment: Why do you think removing the '$i$' lets the formula work?  It is just as essential as every other part of Euler's formula.  Since when did you expect formulas to work after simply removing the parts you don't understand?

Answer (score 4):

$i$ is an [imaginary number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imaginary_unit) that satisfies $i^2=-1$.  You can't just remove it from Euler's formula and expect things to work out.

Answer (score 0):

To extend the previous answer, here is the way to fix your MATLAB code:

```
x=pi/3;
exp(complex(0,1)*x)
complex(cos(x),sin(x))
```

Notice the output from both last statements is

```
0.5000 + 0.8660i
```

as predicted by Euler's Formula.