# For which $n \in \mathbb{N}$ it is true that $x^2+x+1 | (x+1)^n-x^n-1$

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers

I have to find such $n \in \mathbb{N}$ for which $x^2+x+1 | (x+1)^n-x^n-1$.

$x^2+x+1$ has 2 complex roots: $x_1=-((-1)^{(1/3)})$, $x_2=(-1)^{(2/3)}$ so I tried to divide $(x+1)^n-x^n-1$ by $(x-x_1)$ and then $(x-x_2)$ but it was too difficult. Any other hints?

Comment: Hint: What remainder do you get when dividing a polynomal $f(x)$ by $x-x_0$?

Comment: $n=6k-1$ and $n=6k-5$ for natural $k$.

Comment: You can also use $x+1\equiv -x^2\pmod{x^2+x+1}$ and $x^3\equiv 1\pmod{x^2+x+1}$.

Answer (score 2):

As $(x-1)(x^2+x+1)=x^3-1,$ the roots of $x^2+x+1=0$ are complex cube roots$(w,w^2)$ of unity

So, $w^2+w+1=0$

Let $w=e^{2\pi i/3}\implies w^2=e^{-2\pi i/3},-w^2=e^{\pi i(1-2/3)}$

Now using [About Euler's formula $e^{ix}=\cos x+i\sin x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1677967/about-eulers-formula-eix-cos-xi-sin-x),

$$f(w)=(w+1)^n-w^n-1=(-w^2)^n-w^n-1=(e^{\pi i/3})^n-(e^{2\pi i/3})^n-1$$

$$=\cos\dfrac{n\pi}3+i\sin\dfrac{n\pi}3-1-\cos\dfrac{2n\pi}3-i\sin\dfrac{2n\pi}3$$

We need $f(w)=0$

Equate the imaginary & the real parts -

$$\sin\dfrac{2n\pi}3=\sin\dfrac{n\pi}3$$

$\implies$ either $(i)\dfrac{2n\pi}3\equiv\dfrac{n\pi}3\pmod{2\pi}$

or $n\equiv0\pmod6$

But then $\cos\dfrac{n\pi}3-1-\cos\dfrac{2n\pi}3\ne0$

or $(ii)\dfrac{2n\pi}3\equiv\pi-\dfrac{n\pi}3\pmod{2\pi}$

$\implies n\equiv1\pmod2$

Again, $\cos\dfrac{n\pi}3-1-\cos\dfrac{2n\pi}3=\cos\dfrac{n\pi}3-2\cos^2\dfrac{n\pi}3=-\cos\dfrac{n\pi}3\left(2\cos\dfrac{n\pi}3-1\right)$

I hope yo can take it from here!

Answer (score 0):

Let roots of $x^2+x+1$ be $w,w^2$. Thus for this polynomial to divide $P(x)= (x+1)^n-x^n-1$, $w,w^2$ must be roots of $P(x)$.

We must have $(w+1)^n - w^n -1 = 0$ **and** $(w^2+1)^n-w^{2n}-1 = 0$.

Thus we have $(-1)^nw^{2n}-w^n-1 = 0$ **and** $(-1)^nw^n-w^{2n}-1=0$

1. Case $n$ is **even**: Then we have $w^{2n}-w^n-1=0$ and $w^n-w^{2n}-1 = 0$

   - $n$ is multiple of $3$: These give $-1 = 0$, so no solutions in this case.
   - $n$ **not** multiple of $3$: These give $w^n = -w^n$. So no solutions.
2. Case $n$ is **odd**: We have $-w^{2n}-w^n - 1 = 0$ and $-w^n-w^{2n}-1 = 0$.

   - $n$ is multiple of $3$: From second equation we have $-3 = 0$. So no solutions.
   - $n$ **not** multiple of $3$: Now **both** the equations are satisfied. Hence this is the only solution.

So we have that $n$ is **not a multiple** of $2$ or $3$. Hence we can say $n = \boxed {6k\pm 1}$

Comment: $$(1+w)^n=(-w^2)^n=(-1)^nw^{2n}$$ right?

Comment: Bah :( SIlly. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please pinpoint